# Monitor GoDaddy shared hosting server downtime

Tags: server, godaddy, downtime

Can I monitor how long my server remains down on Godaddy shared hosting service?

I have noticed myself once that for several minutes it was down, then back again. It will be helpful if I could see actually how long its getting down per week/month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) seems to be a popular tool for monitoring web site uptime. I haven't used it myself but they do provide SMS and email alerting.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that there is an accepted answer for [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) but when I reviewed their user model I noticed they really didn't have a free solution.  After further researching I ran across [Uptime Robot](http://uptimerobot.com/) although the free edition is for every 5 minute interval but I've been testing it for awhile with good returns.

Since I do not like to just provide an external link there is another solution but I'm only familiar with doing it on a Mac but it could be easily converted to be used with any Linux operating system, like Ubuntu, but I don't use Windows much so I'm unsure of a solution for that.

On my Mac I can use CRON but I prefer launchd, I just simply create a launchd file, reference [launchd Usage](https://gist.github.com/todgru/4503682#launchd-usage) or [Creating and writing into .plist with Terminal OR bah script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379507/creating-and-writing-into-plist-with-terminal-or-bah-script) to run every minute, and with that I can fire a cURL command:

```
curl -I http://www.example.org
```

to return the status code, reference [Getting curl to output HTTP status code?](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code).  With that information you can push into a text file or even a CSV file the time and status code to decipher the exact time frame you're down.

If you wanted to extend your script for the Mac you could take it a step further and integrate TextBelt to send a SMS, reference [Is there any way to send sms to a mobile number using shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203751/is-there-any-way-to-send-sms-to-a-mobile-number-using-shell-script):

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=5551551555 -d "message=hello from OSXDaily.com"
```